# What is the lowest OSX version for submitting to the App Store?

Tags: macos

I have looked, but I cannot get a version of Application Loader old enough to install on OSX10.5.6 . I would hate to have to buy a mac just to upload my app to the app store. I think I can install xcode 3.1 (downloading now), but I do not see anything about application loader being a part of 3.1? Any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: How are you going to build your application without latest XCode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now you should already publish app that supports iOS 7...and you need at least XCode 5 for that (which means at least Mac OS X 10.8).

You really need a Mac with recent OS X. I think this policy is not really fair but it is the way it works.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I can pick up a cheap laptop that will work, until they up it again. I cannot believe their business model!

Comment: Hes asking about Mac OS X not iOS